# How can I save terminale output from certain folder (ls command) to txt file? For Pycharm

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I want to save output data from terminale to txt file.
My code here:

```
def file_exist():
    os.system('/Users/user/Library/LaunchAgents/ls > ~/PycharmProjects/Test_Project/File_new.txt')
    time.sleep(3)
    f = open ('File_new.txt', 'r')
    x = f.read()
    y = str(x)
    print (y)
    return y
```

Answer: No such file or directory.

What is my mistake?

Comment: /Users/`user` the name is user in your computer?

Comment: Yes, it is test user.

Comment: OK your are opening the File_new from current dir where it is saved in pycharm.. Am I right?Doing like this what happens? `f = open ('~/PycharmProjects/Test_Project/File_new.txt', 'r')`

Comment: The same answer, problem that I can't execute ls command.

Comment: Why do you use `/Users/user/Library/LaunchAgents/ls` instead of just `ls`?

Comment: Command should be executed from Pycharm.

Comment: @Vas23Vewe so? it should work from Pycharm. Give it a try...

Comment: No, it does not work. The same answer.

Comment: Does this command work directly called from the terminal?

Comment: In terminal I execute it in two steps: cd to my directory, and the second command ls.
Of course, it works good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

os.system('**ls** /Users/user/Library/LaunchAgents/ > /PycharmProjects/Test_Project/File_new.txt')

The idea to write command at first. It works for me in this way.